In postgres, why does (5999.999999999999::float8)::numeric = 6000?
I've seen some related questions but none that gave a satisfying answer to this.
select
    ((5999.999999999999)::numeric) as num,
    ((5999.999999999999)::float8) as f64,
    ((5999.999999999999)::float8)::numeric as f64_to_num,
    ((5999.999999999999)::numeric)::float8 as num_to_f64;

      num          |      f64          | f64_to_num |      num_to_f64       
-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------------
 5999.999999999999 | 5999.999999999999 |    6000    | 5999.999999999999
(1 row)

This is surprisingly inconsistent, because a number that's represented in the same place in numeric and float8, I wouldn't expect it to round up when converting.
What's going wrong?

links to the related questions may be useful

The conversion from float8 (double precision) to numeric is performed by the PostgreSQL function float8_numeric(). That function uses snprintf() to convert the floating-point value to a string with a precision of DBL_DIG:
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.*g", DBL_DIG, val);

The result is then converted to a numeric.
Now DBL_DIG is 15 on my Linux system, and 5999.999999999999 rounded to a precision of 15 is 6000.
